# PDF Flipbook functionality in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Is there any Javascript library or plugin for a flip animation of a PDF file? if not, then how can I use this effect on my webpage?

Answer (score 1):

Look at any pdf viewer and that ability is not generally available, What you will find in any flipbook is a viewer like Mozilla PDF.js which replaces the pdf with images.
So the simplest answer is use any conversion lib like https://3dflipbook.net/ or https://dearflip.com/responsive-html5-flipbook-jquery-plugin/

or any one of the OVER 1000 here on GitHub https://github.com/search?q=flipbook
this one looks nice https://kubil-ismail.github.io/Pdf-Flipbook/
or what about https://notshriram.github.io/React-Flipbook-Demo/